# ¿Qué quiere decir "remecer"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, chile

Hace días ya leí el titular [El escándalo de espionaje que **remece** a los empresarios chilenos](https://elpais.com/internacional/2017/05/26/america/1495823742_391036.html). La noticia pertenece a un periódico español, pero está redactada desde Chile, por lo que entiendo que usa chilenismos.

El DLE indica:

> [**remecer**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VscGQja)
>   Del lat. *remiscēre*.
>   1. tr. Mover reiteradamente algo de un lado a otro. U. t. c. prnl.

Pero no lo veo demasiado explicativo para el caso por la serie de frases en la noticia del tipo:

> Un escándalo ha golpeado este viernes al corazón de los empresarios chilenos.

o

> "Este episodio, inédito en la SOFOFA, es inmensamente dañino para nuestra institución, para el empresariado, para la credibilidad pública y para nuestro país. En lo personal, a los directivos de nuestra organización empresarial, les duele y afecta que se hayan vulnerado principios básicos de respeto a las personas e instituciones", ha señalado el organismo a través de un comunicado.

o

> Los empresarios locales han condenado en cadena el espionaje

Que me hacen pensar en un significado del tipo que el caso ha *sacudido*, *soliviantado* o similares, a los empresarios.

¿Tiene esta palabra algún significado adicional o matiz que me pasa desapercibido?

Comment: Hacer temblar sería, ¿no?

Comment: I think our newspapers must be more graphic: "Chilean businesses rocked by spy scandal" seems the obvious meaning here. Not sure exactly which of your suggestions or that of @guifa has precisely the same sense.

Comment: @mdewey rocking wouldn't be that bad of a translation, since it means to move something from one side to another (rocking horse, for instance).

Comment: En Argentina habrían titulado *El escándalo **sacude** a empresarios*, por lo demás, con el mismo significado figurativo.

Comment: Acerca de eso (con *sacudir* por *remecer*): http://imgur.com/a/FjxjG

Comment: @pablodf76 bien visto. Además, [_sacudir_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Wy83HVH) se define casi igual: _Mover violentamente algo a una y otra parte._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Según se puede constatar con algunas búsquedas, en los países andinos (Chile, Bolivia, Perú, Ecuador), donde ocurren habitualmente sismos debido a las características geológicas, se utiliza *remecer* para designar lo que hace con una región un temblor o terremoto (como particularidad hay también una diferencia de grado entre *temblor* y *terremoto* en estos lugares, pero ése es otro tema). En Argentina, Uruguay y Paraguay es más frecuente el uso de *sacudir* con este significado (cuando en artículos periodísticos aparece *remecer* casi invariablemente se refieren a sucesos de la zona andina, probablemente tomando las palabras *verbatim* de una agencia de noticias local).

Para mí está claro que *remecer* en el titular citado tiene la misma función figurativa que *sacudir* en los que habitualmente se ven en los medios argentinos: un escándalo *remece* o *sacude* a una institución o grupo de personas de la misma manera que un terremoto sacude a una ciudad o región, haciendo que las personas se sientan menos seguras sobre sus pies, que caigan al suelo ellas o se derrumben sus simbólicas "construcciones", y que haya víctimas (figuradamente: pérdida de reputación, fortuna o libertad).

*Remecer* y *sacudir* en este uso, que remite al de los temblores (y puede también asociarse a explosiones o choques), son verbos que connotan pérdida de control del objeto en manos de una fuerza superior (si no fuera superior tendríamos titulares como "Los empresarios resisten el escándalo").

Comment: Fantástico análisis, gracias Pablo. Comentar que en España se usa también _sacudir_ con este sentido y es común en la prensa. La distinción _temblor_ y _terremoto_ daría para otra pregunta, me lo apunto :)

Comment: Causar conmoción, escándalo, desconcierto