# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "terremoto" y "temblor"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales

De una pregunta relativa al [uso figurativo del verbo *remecer*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21759/14627) surgió (en un aparte) que existe una diferencia, en el vocabulario de ciertos países, entre los términos *terremoto* y *temblor*. Yo sabía que se hacía esta distinción, basada en la intensidad percibida del sismo, [en Chile](http://www.t13.cl/noticia/nacional/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-temblor-sismo-y-terremoto), pero resulta que parece ser común en otros países, no sólo de la región geológicamente activa de los Andes sino también incluso [en Puerto Rico](http://www.primerahora.com/noticias/puerto-rico/nota/tembloroterremotoeslomismo-982800/). De todas formas es difícil saber porque los medios no siempre registran el vocabulario coloquial o las distinciones hechas por la gente de a pie, y a veces los medios de un país copian y pegan noticias de agencias de otros países.

Mi pregunta es: ¿cuál es la diferencia entre *temblor* y *terremoto*, si existe, en los distintos dialectos del castellano? Adicionales a ésa serían: ¿hay alguna otra palabra para designar a los sismos? Por caso, ¿*sismos* o *seísmos*? ¿Qué connotaciones tienen estos términos? Sería interesante crear un pequeño mapa de la distribución de los mismos.

Comment: Muy buena pregunta. Acabo de descubrir que [_sismo_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y1wOHBE) es sinónimo de terremoto; en España decimos mucho [_seísmo_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XU8t70w), de raíz igual pero sin pasar por el francés.

Comment: @fedorqui Eso fue un error. :) Es verdad lo de sismo/seísmo, lo voy a añadir explícitamente a la pregunta.

Comment: Ah vale :) Edito mi comentario para quitar la parte de la errata pues :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aunque etimológicamente son lo mismo (y en otros idiomas no existe distinción tan clara), parece haber ido decantando un uso variado en distintos países, en parte por necesidades prácticas (legales y de la industria aseguradora).

La palabra *sismo* (o *seísmo*) tiende a mantener un ámbito más formal, y a agrupar a ambos términos. Por su parte, *terremoto* y *temblor*, cuando se distingue, denotan respectivamente a los más y menos violentos, pero los criterios para dividir varían:

*(esta lista está incompleta, puedes ayudar a incluir nuevos países)*

### Por daños:

- **Costa Rica**. [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un sismo, un temblor y un terremoto?](http://rsn.ucr.ac.cr/documentos/educativos/sismologia/325-cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-un-sismo-un-temblor-y-un-terremoto)
- **Guatemala**. [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre temblor, sismo y terremoto?](http://www.soy502.com/articulo/cual-diferencia-entre-temblor-sismo-terremoto-32419)
- **Perú**. [¿QUÉ DIFERENCIA EXISTE ENTRE SISMO, TEMBLOR Y TERREMOTO?](http://portal.igp.gob.pe/sites/default/files/images/documents/sismos/preguntas_frecuentes/2.pdf)

### Por intensidad del movimiento:

- **Chile**. [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre temblor, sismo y terremoto?](http://www.t13.cl/noticia/nacional/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-temblor-sismo-y-terremoto)

Es probable que no sea coincidencia que los mismos criterios también se usen en la clasificación técnica: la escala de *Mercalli* gradúa los sismos según percepción y daño, mientras que las escalas de *Richter* y de [*Magnitud de Momentos*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_magnitude_scale) se fijan en sus aspectos cinemáticos.

Otro término para designar este fenómeno es [***movimiento telúrico***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/movimiento_tel%C3%BArico). Aunque el DLE sólo recoge el [adjetivo](http://dle.rae.es/?w=tel%C3%BArico) como subterráneo o relativo a la Tierra, es de uso [relativamente común](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22movimiento%20tel%C3%BArico%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: Me recuerda un viejo chiste en que le envían un telegrama urgente a Pancho Villa durante la revolución "Movimiento telúrico aproxímase. Epicentro localízase en esa ciudad" La respuesta a los tres días decia: "A Telurio lo agarramos y fusilamos de inmediato. Epifanio se nos fué porque nos agarró un temblor que mejor no les cuento...."

Answer (score 1):

Al menos en México, se usa indistintamente temblor o terremoto, sin connotación alguna por la intensidad, **cuando el contexto indica claramente que se trata de un movimiento telúrico.**

Sin embargo, **terremoto** se usa exclusivamente para el fenómeno sísmico, mientras que **temblor** se puede referir a cualquier movimiento oscilatorio, independientemente de su causa, lo que nos deja divertidos enunciados como:

> después del *terremoto*, todos sintieron *temblores* en los brazos por el susto, más fuertes que el candelabro, que quedó *temblando* por largos minutos..

Answer (score 0):

Pues aquí al centro-norte de México normalmente **un terremoto es más fuerte que un sismo o temblor**. De esta manera, por ejemplo el movimiento telúrico ocurrido en México el 19-S fue un terremoto, mientras que sus réplicas u otros temblores pequeños (que apenas se sienten) no son terremotos, sino temblores o sismos.